# Get notified of DataContext changed in a WPF Resource

Tags: wpf, binding, collectionviewsource

I'm having an annoying problem with WPF binding.  Basically, I declare a FrameworkElement in my UserControl's resources, but that item doesn't seem to get notified when the DataContext of the parent UserControl changes.

Basically, in my UserControl I have a Popup in the ItemTemplate for an ItemsControl.  In that Popup, I needed to bind to something in the parent view's ViewModel, so I came up with what I thought was a clever trick.  Taking a cue from CollectionViewSource, I figured I'd just bind my parent's view model to a resource, and then use that resource to get to the ViewModel from the DataTemplate, like so:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <cont:ViewModelSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="ParentViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

So that later I can use it like:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ViewModel.OpenEntity, Source={StaticResource ParentViewModel}}"
```

This all would seem to work *except* that the DataContext on the ViewModelSource doesn't get reset when the DataContext of the UserControl gets reset.  Right now, I'm making this work hackily: setting the resource's DataContext in code-behind on the UserControl's DataContextChanged event.

I took a look in Reflector to see how CollectionViewSource does this, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything special.

Anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found a solution.

First i tryed to set my ViewModel as DataContext of my root element. wrong.

Then i tryed to set my ViewModel as Resource and set binding source of my root element to the Resource. wrong.

Finally I created a IValueConverter to convert a Model (witch is DataContext of the control) to a ViewModel. Then I Bind DataContext of my root element with the converter.

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <local:PersonToControllerConverter x:Key="PersonToControllerConverter"/>

    <!--<local:PersonController x:Key="controller"
        Value="{Binding}"
        Parent="{Binding Path=DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
        />-->

</UserControl.Resources>



<Border x:Name="root" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" >
    <Border.DataContext>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PersonToControllerConverter}">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Border.DataContext>

    <!--DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource controller}}">-->

    <!--<Border.DataContext>
        <local:PersonController
                    Value="{Binding}"
                    Parent="{Binding Path=DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                    />
    </Border.DataContext>-->
```

I think that when the DataContext breaks the binding in an element, when the datacontext changes on a root element, it stops on the broken binding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to create a middle object that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.